# Function expects list when it should be expecting a string

Tags: ocaml

```
type table = string * string list * string list list;;

let studentTable = ("Student",
                    ["ID";"Name";"Gender";"Course"],
                    [["2";"Jim";"Male";"Geography"];
                     ["4";"Linnea";"Female";"Economics"];
                     ["7";"Steve";"Male";"Informatics"];
                     ["9";"Hannah";"Female";"Geography"]]);;

let rec restrictMatch(attribute,value,attributeList,dataList) =
  match (attribute,value,attributeList,dataList) with
    ([],_,_,_) -> false
  | (_,[],_,_) -> false
  | (_,_,[],_) -> false
  | (_,_,_,[]) -> false
  | ((wh::wt),value,(ah::at),(h::t)) ->
      if wh=ah && value=h
      then true
      else restrictMatch(attribute,value,at,t)

          
let rec restrictRows(attribute,value,attributeList,dataList) =
  match (attributeList,dataList) with 
    (_,[]) -> []
  | ([],_) -> []
  | ((ah::at),(h::t)) ->
      if restrictMatch(attribute,value,attributeList,h)
      then h::restrictRows(attribute,value,attributeList,t)
      else restrictRows(attribute,value,attributeList,t)

          
let restriction (attribute,value,table) =
  match table with 
    (name,attributeList,dataList)->
      (attributeList,restrictRows(attribute,value,attributeList,dataList))
```

I'm trying to implement the relational algebra function of 'restriction' using OCaml. However when I try to run the 'restriction' function as so:

```
restriction ("Gender", "Female", studentTable)
```

Ocaml throws an exception at me as so:

> Line 1, characters 13-21:
> Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type
> 'a list

However, it doesn't make sense to me as I'm 99% sure I'm not passing a list anywhere in the code.

Comment: Try adding some type annotations. That'll narrow down the possible causes significantly.

Comment: in `restrictionRows` you match `attribute` with `[]` so it's a list for ocaml. And in `restriction` you pass `"Gender"` as `attribute` which is then used in `restrictionRows` which wants a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type checker is 100% sure that you are using `attribute` as list.
And indeed, you are comparing `attribute` with the empty list in:

```ml
let rec restrictMatch(attribute,value,attributeList,dataList) =
  match (attribute,value,attributeList,dataList) with
  | [],_,_,_ -> false
```

Aside(s):

Using tuples for function is not idiomatic in OCaml where curried function are preferred:

```ml
let rec restrictMatch attribute value attributeList dataList = ...
```

Similarly, it is simpler to use a let-binding to bind a tuple:

```ml
let name, attributeList, dataList = table in
...
```

rather than `match table with`

It would be also useful to setup your editor with merlin so you can query the type of functions when you disagree with the type-checker.